# Is there alternative for imread command to reduce delay in matlab program?

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, dot-product

I am having 2900 images in this path G:\newdatabase\  It is taking too much time to read images.For dot product also it is taking too much time.

Questions:

1.Is there any alternative for imread command which increases performance?

2.Is there any alternative for dot command which increases performance?

Source code i tried:

```
  srcFiles = dir('G:\newdatabase\*.jpg');  % the folder in which ur images exists
    for b = 1 : length(srcFiles)
        filename = strcat('G:\newdatabase\',srcFiles(b).name);
        Imgdata = imread(filename);
```

Source code i tried:

```
for i = 1:aa
    pare = dot(NormImage,u(:,i));
    p = [p; pare];
end
```

Comment: For 2 - `pare = sum(bsxfun(@times,NormImage,u))'`. For 1 - Don't think there's any alternative to imread, but maybe save them offline as a single mat file to store all those image files before running the code and then load just that single mat file when running code?

Comment: To read the images faster, multithreading is required. Either use a parfor/parallel computing toolbox or implement it in Java using threads.

Comment: If you need to do this often it might help if you store the results of `imread` in mat files and work with these - these usually load much quicker.